# Flutter SingleChildScrollView - disable pulling down the top?

Tags: flutter

How can I set the top position fixed? I just want users to scroll down without letting them pull down (it has a motion of pull down to refresh and I do not want it to be pulled down).

How can I make SingleChildScrollView's top part will never be pulled down and users just scroll down?

Comment: physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),

Comment: this does not work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by defining a scroll controller assign to your scroll list widget.

Use the controller to listen the current position and prevent it scroll to top

```
final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.offset <= 0) {
       // if <=0 offset, we can immediate to bring it to 0 position
        scrollController.jumpTo(0);
      } 
    });
  }
... Your widget 
SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: scrollController, <-- remember to add controller 
child: ... your scroll list


@override
  void dispose() {
   // Don't forget to dispose it
    scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```